# How to sort directories first in dired?

Tags: dired, osx

I add `(setq dired-listing-switches "-lXGh --group-directories-first")` in my init.el

But when I go into dired mode.

> ls does not support --dired; see ‘dired-use-ls-dired’ for more details.
>   insert-directory: Listing directory failed but ‘access-file’ worked

this error occurs. How can I solve this problem?
I want to sort directories first in dired mode.
My environment is macOS Sierra and emacs 25.1

Comment: On OSX, I still use Core Utilities to have a version of `ls` that permits me to sort directories first.  I haven't yet upgraded to Sierra, so I don't know what type of `ls` version it has:  See:  "**error in dired sorting on OS X**":  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20027876/2112489  In a nutshell, certain versions of `ls` do not support group directories first.  You can open a shell and type help for `ls` to see what command line options are supported.

Answer (score 8):

As @lawlist mentioned, you need to install `coreutils` as the `ls` command which ships with mac does not have the option to sort directories first. If you have homebrew, you could just type `brew install coreutils`. This will also install `gls` which emacs can use. Add this to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq insert-directory-program "gls" 
      dired-use-ls-dired t)
```

After adding this, your Dired listing values will work again on macOS

Answer (score 8):

1. Use standard Emacs library `ls-lisp`.

   ```
   (require 'ls-lisp)
   ```
2. Customize these two user options (you can just use `setq` to set them in your init file, if you prefer):

   - **`ls-lisp-dirs-first`** to `t`
   - **`ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program`** to `nil`

---

If you want to be able to sort Dired listings in many ways, using a menu, then load library [**`dired-sort-menu.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired-sort-menu.el). (You might also want to use [`dired-sort-menu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired-sort-menu%2b.el).)

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the error, you could set

```
(setq dired-use-ls-dired  nil)
```

(see [entering dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired-Enter.html) in the manual)

---

I don't know if mac os x's ls now supports sorting in the way you intended, though. I installed coreutils via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to have a GNU `ls`. And set

```
(setq insert-directory-program "/usr/local/bin/ls")
;; (setq dired-listing-switches "your settings")
```

---

If the `ls-use-ls-dired` option above does not work for you, and you don't want to install a separate binary, you could use emacs' ls emulation via

```
(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil)
(require 'ls-lisp)
```

and then set

```
(setq ls-lisp-dirs-first t)
```

see [ls in lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/ls-in-Lisp.html#ls-in-Lisp) in the manual.

---

nb: Best wrap the options of your choice into a

```
(add-hook 'dired-load-hook
  (lambda () ...)
```